# How to test for if all players of a particular team are on a particular area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I'm making a minigame map in Minecraft and I cant figure out how can I test if all players from a particular team are in a particular area using Command Blocks (with a radius of 8 blocks, if all players are present the Command Block should give a Redstone output). Can someone help me by providing the correct Minecraft command?

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve this yourself before asking here. We're volunteers, so don't waste our time without putting in some yourself.

Comment: The only difference with the linked question is that you also have to include the team in the target selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command, but you *can* use `/testfor @a[team=<teamname>,rm=8]`, and invert the comparator output.

Comment: I tried ur command ash4fun but it would send signal if any player of the same team goes to that area. I want to send signal only if all playera of a specific team (say hiders) are present in that area.

Comment: What the command does is looks for anyone outside the specified area, and returns true unless it finds someone

Comment: Okkkkk now to get it thx soooooooooooooo much